# How to set the Azure default TenantId in the custom private DbContext package through options configurations

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, visual-studio, entity-framework-core

I am using my company's custom DbContext as a private package.
The package implementation looks like this:

```
namespace Company.Data.CompanyServices

    {
        public class CompanyServicesDbContext : DbContext
        {
            public virtual DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
    
            public virtual DbSet<Administration> Administrations { get; set; }
    
            public virtual DbSet<MfaStatus> MfaStatuses { get; set; }
             .....
             public CompanyServicesDbContext (DbContextOptions options)
                : base(options)
            {
            }
            .......
        }
    }
```

I want to set the default Azure `tenantId` to get the token and operate the db.

The issue is that I have different Azure Tenants, and if I am not logged into the right Tenant, my application fails when I run it locally using my Visual Studio.

I know that it is because my application takes the wrong token from the other Tenants, I am logged into.

If I was creating my application dbContext, I could have achieved this by the following implementation:

```
     public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
            {
                var tokenRequestContext = new TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://database.windows.net/" }, null, null,
                tenantId = "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx" // passing the default tenantId here
                );
                var accessToken = (new DefaultAzureCredential()).GetToken(tokenRequestContext);
                var conn = (Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)this.Database.GetDbConnection();
                conn.AccessToken = accessToken.Token;
    
            }
```

But I am using the private DbContext package, and I cannot change the package code.

Is there a way to pass the token, through configuration options, when I am using the private package and consume the implementation from it?

Answer (score 1):

Since this is an internal package, the package maintainer should provide you with either:

- The option to register the extension your self with a neat helper
  method and allow the passing of the tenantId from you
- Allow/expose some kind of appSetting section for you to add to your config, such that you only add a config value, and then the package should internally lookup the section ( much like it probably does to obtain the connection strings ) so that you are not aware of how it is been used, but you do need to remember to add the config to your apps config file

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Do you have any code samples?

Comment: dont have anything ready, but you need to make a simple extension method to encapsulate builder.Services.addDBContext and pass there the settings you want, along with the tenantId

Comment: I will make a tryout and share the results. Thank you!